# Convert nested for-loop to list comp and filter perfect squares from resultant list of dicts

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension, nested-loops

I have written the following code:

```
a_list = []

for x in range(5):
    a_list.append(dict())
    for y in range(5):
        if (x != 0 and y != 0) and (x * x != x * y):
            a_list[-1][y] = x * y
```

The result is:

```
[{}, {2: 2, 3: 3, 4: 4}, {1: 2, 3: 6, 4: 8}, {1: 3, 2: 6, 4: 12}, {1: 4, 2: 8, 3: 12}]
```

But, I am having to get the same result using a list comprehension. How could I do this please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write it, like so:

```
a_list = [{y: x * y for y in range(5) if (x and y) and (x * x != x * y)}
          for x in range(5)]    

# [{}, {2: 2, 3: 3, 4: 4}, {1: 2, 3: 6, 4: 8}, {1: 3, 2: 6, 4: 12}, {1: 4, 2: 8, 3: 12}]
```

Sometimes a `list comprehension` is less readable or more complex than nested `for loops`, though.

Answer (score 3):

The following nested comprehension will work:

```
[{y: x*y for y in range(5) if y and x*x != x*y} for x in range(5)]
# [{}, {2: 2, 3: 3, 4: 4}, {1: 2, 3: 6, 4: 8}, {1: 3, 2: 6, 4: 12}, {1: 4, 2: 8, 3: 12}]
```

The inner dict comprehension's conditions are a bit simplified as `x*x != x*y` already implies `x != 0`.

Answer (score 1):

Your if statement can be simplified some:

```
[{y: x*y for y in range(1, 5) if 0 != x != y} for x in range(5)]
```

Which gives:

```
[{}, {2: 2, 3: 3, 4: 4}, {1: 2, 3: 6, 4: 8}, {1: 3, 2: 6, 4: 12}, {1: 4, 2: 8, 3: 12}]
```

Notice that the inner range doesn't need the zero index.

Answer (score 0):

Some very good answers already here. Here's my attempt:

```
a_list = [dict() for x in range(5)]
[[a_list[x].update({y:x * y}) for y in range(5) if (x != 0 and y != 0) and (x * x != x * y)] for x in range(5)]
```